# Is a class type in the Java Language Specification permitted to be its own supertype?

Tags: java, jls

The [Java Language Specification says, in section 4.10](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10), in part:

> The *supertypes* of a type are obtained by reflexive and transitive closure over the direct supertype relation, written S >₁ T, which is defined by rules given later in this section. We write S :> T to indicate that the supertype relation holds between S and T.

(I've picked version 11 but this is pretty foundational stuff so it hardly matters.)

To keep things simple here, let's say we're dealing with non-generic classes (like `String.class`; it doesn't declare any type parameters).  In that case, [the (relevant) rules defining the direct supertype relation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.2) are as follows:

> Given a non-generic type declaration C, the *direct supertypes* of the type C are all of the following:
>
> The *direct superclass* of C (§8.1.4) [i.e. the `extends` clause]
>
> The *direct superinterfaces* of C (§8.1.5) [i.e. the `implements` clause].
>
> The type `Object`, if C is an interface type with no direct superinterfaces (§9.1.3).

By these rules, the direct supertypes of `String.class` do not include `String.class`.  They include things like `Object`, `Serializable`, `CharSequence` and a parameterized type denoting `Comparable<String>` (and maybe `Constable` and `ConstantDesc` for more modern JDKs).
This is all fine so far.

Then it says, in part:

> S is a *proper supertype* of T, written S > T, if S :> T and S ≠ T.

So `Object` is a proper supertype of `String` because `Object` is a supertype of `String` (a direct one as it happens) and is also not equal to `String`.

That *seems* to imply that (S :> T and S = T) is a valid state of affairs (i.e. S is a supertype of T and S is T, so S is a supertype of S), because otherwise why would you bother to introduce the notion of a "proper supertype"?  What would an *improper* supertype be (my invented term)?  Is there one?  How do you "get that" from the direct supertype relation?  Where in the JLS is it permitted for a type to be its own supertype?

Comment: A [reflexive closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_closure) includes the identity relation, so the "improper supertype" of T is T.

Comment: Thank you! So S is not a direct supertype of S, but it is a supertype of S.